# jQuery toggle focus / blur

Tags: jquery, focus, toggle

How can I toggle an element's CSS on focus/blur with jQuery?

```
$('.answerSpace').bind('blur', function(){
$('.normProf').toggleClass('opacProf');
});

$('.answerSpace').bind('focus', function(){
    $('.opacProf').toggleClass('normProf');
});
```

So now I have this.  But it doesn't quite work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$('.answerSpace').bind('blur', function(){ $('.normProf').removeClass("normProf").addClass('opacProf'); });
$('.answerSpace').bind('focus', function(){ $('.opacProf').removeClass("opacProf").addClass('normProf'); });
```

Answer (score 27):

Check this out, it's exactly how y'all should do jQuery focus toggle..

### Basic use case:

```js
$('input').on('focus blur', toggleFocus);

function toggleFocus(e){
    console.log(e.type)

    if( e.type == 'focusin' ){ 
      // do something on focus
    }
    else{
      // do something else on blur
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution here.

Comment: It should be `if( e.type == 'focus' )`

Comment: @TayyabChaudhary - Not necessarily - when doing event delegation. [Please read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event)

Comment: @vsync `if( e.type == 'focusin' )` wasn't working for me in jQuery, so I checked `console.log(e.type);` and it returns `focus` on focusing the input field and `blur` on focus out. That's why I replaced `focusin` with `focus`. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Please write the version of jQuery & Browser type. Printing the type is **no** something helpful in this particular case, since `focus` events do not bubble. I have been using the `focusin` event for over 12 years now, on many systems.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if I get you right, you can use [onblur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [onfocus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) events, with the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function:

```
$('#yourelement').bind('blur', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('your-class');
});

$('#yourelement').bind('focus', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('your-class');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, if I use this, the css changes on the first focus.  Then it doesn't change back on the blur.  Nor the second blur.  But actually on the third blur it then reverts to the previous css.  The code I'm using is above.

Comment: You could combine the `bind('blur focus')`

Answer (score 1):

Blur only gets active when you leave an input, so you can use it to remove the focus again.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 1px #ccc');
});
                    
$('input').blur(function(){ 
    $(this).css('box-shadow', 'none');
});
```